# How to animate in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I've found this example in w3schools and want to modify its animation into my liking. Basically it has two divs, one as a container and the other is for the animation. Originally the animated div can go one direction from top to bottom or top to left etc. But what I want to happen is, as soon as it animates already from top to bottom, I want it to move back from bottom to top. How to achieve this?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
#container {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
background: yellow;
}
#animate {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 145px;
background-color: red;
}
</style>
<body>

<p>
<button onclick="Move()">Click</button>
</p> 

<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
</div>

<script>
function Move() {
var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
var pos = 0;
var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
function frame() {

if (pos < 300) {
  pos++;
  elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
  elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px'; 
}

}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is a great reference of animations http://robertpenner.com/easing/ and the rest https://www.google.es/search?q=robert+penner+animation+javascript&oq=robert+penner+animation+javascript&aqs=chrome..69i57.6743j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=+animation+javascript

Comment: You have to set a "direction", otherwise if you only check vertical position it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using keyframes instead of js?

```css
#container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
}
#animate {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 145px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: move 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    top: 0;
  }
  50% {
    top: 300px;
  }
  100% {
    top: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="animate"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Its better to use css animations, but if you want to do in this way then you have to set a direction. I modify your code and add direction in it.

```js
function Move() {
var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
var pos = 0;
var direction = "down";
var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
function frame() {
if (direction=="down") {
  pos++;
  elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
  elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px'; 
} else {
  pos--;
  elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
  elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px'; 
}
if (pos == 300) {
  direction = "up";
}
if (pos == 0) {
  direction = "down";
}
}
}
```

```css
#container {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
background: yellow;
}
#animate {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 145px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
<button onclick="Move()">Click</button>
</p> 

<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep a variable to check which direction the box is going and change it based on the boundary conditions. Like if you reach position 0 you can make direction down and if you reach position 300 make direction up.

```js
function Move() {
var elem = document.getElementById("animate");   
var pos = 0;
var direction = 'down';
var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
function frame() {

if (pos >= 300) {
   direction = 'up';
} else if (pos <= 0) {
direction = 'down';
}
 if (direction === 'down'){
  pos++; 
} else if (direction === 'up'){
  pos--;
}
  elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
  elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px'; 


}
}
```

```css
#container {
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
background: yellow;
}
#animate {
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
position: absolute;
left: 145px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>
<button onclick="Move()">Click</button>
</p> 

<div id ="container">
<div id ="animate"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify you `frame()` function to check direction and then add/subtract position accordingly E.g

```
function frame() {

  if(pos >= 300 ) {
    dir = 1;
  }else if (pos <=0) {
    dir = 0;
  }

  if (dir ===0) {
    pos++;
  } else {
    pos--;
  }

   elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; 
   elem.style.bottom = pos + 'px'; 
}
```

You can find this working on this [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/cuseyupora/edit?html,output)